# Not able to copy paste multiple component and pages in Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013

I am not able to copy paste multiple component and pages in Tridion 2013 SP1 .
When i see in firebug i can see as shown in screen shot. It is working fine for me in my Local and QA environment .

[image]

The following call is getting executed continuously

WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/MultipleOperations.svc/QueryMultipleOperations

Let me know what should i do in this scenario .

Comment: I can see the below error' in Event viewer . Access is denied for the user sapient\rdixi1. I have MTSUSER in place as well.. Every time I do a batch operation it gives the above error in event viewer .

Comment: I am doing the batch operation by my ID say sapient\Jitender but in event viewer i am getting a error "Access denied for the user sapient\rdixi1" . This user sapient\rdixi1 is a deleted user in the trustees table.I dont know why it is going to this user when i do a batch operation.

Comment: I changed `Tridion.ContentManager.config.xml` `administratorUserName="DOMAIN\Administrator"` Restarted services. In event viewer I see the message: Access Is denied for the user `DOMAIN\AnotherUser` Seems we have another configuration, and user `DOMAIN\AnotherUser` is specified there. What other configuration places I can look in?

Answer (score 11):

If you can perform single operations fine but not multiple (batch) operations, check that your `Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor` service is started on the Content Manager.

Also check the `administratorUserName` attribute's value for the `configuration/batching` node in your `Tridion.ContentManager.config.xml`

Comment: IF Batch Processor is running - check eventLog for error entries. Sometimes batch operation can not be executed due to another errors and they must be logged into event-viewer.

Answer (score 4):

For people who are still looking for the answer, just make sure that the "MTS user name" that is being used in the Batch service, is present in "Trustees" table, is enabled, and set as an admin. 
This can typically happen when you take a dump from another environment but forget to update the Trustees table.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you haven't got a popup blocker running. If you have it will interfere with the confirmation dialog, and your paste won't work.

Answer (score 3):

In a load-balanced CMS scenario, I have seen it where this will only work properly when the administratorUserName is using the domain mtsuser rather than a local mtsuser

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the existing batch operations present.

From the PowerShell command prompt, enter the command 
`Remove-TcmBatches`

Also you can send parameter "All"  if you want to delete all the completed and non completed batches

Check http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/ and search for purging batches.

Please make sure you have MTSUser in place.

Comment: I have done this as well and nothing happened. I have updated the question with error from Event logs .Please let me know what else i can look for .