# Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor Service Error - Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme

Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor service (windows service) gives below error in event logs on startup. Any suggestions how to fix this up

```
Access is denied for the user {Domain-Name}\dev-MTSUser.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Batching
Errorcode: 770
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine.LoadAccessToken(String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueuingEngine..ctor(String userName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Batching.BatchProcessor.QueueConsumerHandler.DoWork()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to copy paste multiple component and pages in Tridion 2013 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/not-able-to-copy-paste-multiple-component-and-pages-in-tridion-2013-sp1)

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate question. The answer may be the same, but the two questions describe quite distinct symptoms. If someone's looking for one or the other, either question can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

As per my [previous answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/not-able-to-copy-paste-multiple-component-and-pages-in-tridion-2013-sp1), check the `administratorUserName` attribute's value for the `configuration/batching` node in your `Tridion.ContentManager.config.xml`

Comment: make sure dev-mtsuser account isn't locked out too

Comment: administratorUserName attribute's value for the configuration/batching node in Tridion.ContentManager.config.xml is pointing to {Domain-Name}\dev-MTSUser. Anything more on this to check ?

Comment: Yes, that's expected, as that's the user-name in your error message. So as per @WarnerSoditus comment, you now need to check that user is valid on the system, not locked and is allowed to access the Content Manager.

Comment: dev-mtsuser is domain user; its user profile shows its active and not locked; to login to CME i need to reset its password since we do not have its password details available. Is it OK if i reset password for this devmts-user?