# Not able to paste multiple components

Tags: component

The functionality of pasting multiple component is somehow not working in CMS, although the promotion/demotion is working fine.

And I am guessing this is due to the fact that if we paste a single entry, then a dialog of it being a copy appears..and if I select multiple, then the processing is too much for SDL CMS to handle.

Is there any way out of this?

I have also checked the following post:
[Not able to copy paste multiple component and pages in Tridion 2013 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/not-able-to-copy-paste-multiple-component-and-pages-in-tridion-2013-sp1)

Comment: Are you saying even if you are not able to copy and paste 2 items or what's your case? Any error message in event viewer any exception?

Comment: Yes, when I copy any two components and paste them..just info message(pasting [0/2]) is shown...but this process is never completed

Comment: As a quick workaround try restarting Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor service, or have an administrator restart it, on the Content Manager environment(s).

Comment: Starting batch processor has definitely speed up the process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to restart (or start) Tcm Batch Processor process. This process is in charge of executing batch jobs, like copying or deleting multiple items at once. If this error happens again, you should check logs and contact customer support to investigate the issue further.

Answer (score 1):

I remember this being a known issue when you try to perform a batch operation by selecting multiple components and perform action like copy/paste, delete, publishing etc.

There has been a Hotfix for it if I recalled correctly - Kindly contact the SDL Support and you should be able to get the hotfix for it.

Alternatively, you may confirm that you have 2013 SP1 with all Hotfix Rollup (HR#1, HR#2) - whatever is applicable to you.

Also, would be better to go for an upgrade as 2013 SP1 won't be supported anymore soon.